# Using React.ComponentProps in a generic function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

Apparently, using `React.ComponentProps` is the correct way to extract the component 
property types, however, i can't make it work in a generic function:

Sample component:

```
interface OwnProps {
  value: string;
}

const TestComponent: SFC<OwnProps> = (props) => {
  const { } = props;
  return (
    <div />
  );
};
```

Generic function:

```
function myFunction<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>
 (Component: React.ReactType, props: React.ComponentProps<T>) {
  // implementation
}
```

Function Usage:

```
myFunction(TestComponent, {
  value: 1  // not detecting invalid value
});
```

As you can see the `value` is assigned with a numeric value but the compiler is not detecting the error.

one way to do this is to use the function as follow:

```
myFunction<typeof TestComponent>(TestComponent, {
  value: 1
});
```

it works, but i am curious how it can be done without using `typeof`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function myFunction<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>
 (Component: React.ReactType, props: React.ComponentProps<T>) {
  // implementation
}
```

In this definition, Component can be any React.ReactType. There's no mention of T, so this is not going to enforce any relationship between the component and the props.

Instead, i believe you want this:

```
function myFunction<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>
  (Component: T, props: React.ComponentProps<T> {
  // implementation
}
```

Comment: excellent, replacing React.ReactType with T did solve the problem. thank you